# OOB component Customization in AEM 6.2

Tags: adobe, aem

We have a requirement to customize the OOB **Assest share and assest editor**component in AEM 6.2.(available at /libs/dam/components/asseteditor &/libs/dam/components/assetshare path respectively)

Few challenges I can see:
1.The component dialog is available only in Classic UI but we want the same in touch UI mode.
2.Can we get the Java code of these components so that we can customize the functionality?
What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: The assetshare and asseteditor components are there to make pages that layer the DAM interface with a simpler functionality. Theses components are not in TouchUI (as of 6.2) but even if they were, these would be like core components with limited functionality. You can overlay these and provide your own templates and components just like normal component extension. All the code is in JSP under the respective components.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.One more concern is that these components are n't responsive.Do i need to make each component responsive?

Comment: Yes. As of 6.2 these aren't responsive so you will need to rewrite them. Remember that these are utility components as the generated page is responsive do RoI in conversion may not be worth it. Just a thought.

Comment: Mark answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assetshare and asseteditor components are there to make pages that layer the DAM interface with a simpler functionality. Theses components are not in TouchUI (as of 6.2) but even if they were, these would be like core components with limited functionality. You can overlay these and provide your own templates and components just like normal component extension. All the code is in JSP under the respective components.

These components are not responsive but the genrated page can be made responsive.